# Android app crash after restored from background in react native

Tags: android, react-native, crash, back-button

I am developing android app with react native.
It works well but it crashes when restore from background.
For example,
If I go to some activity and go to home screen by pressing `back` button several times, and restore it from app list, it crashes.
it shows white blink screen and block buttons.
But If I go to home screen by click `home` button and restore it, it doesn't crash.
(it shows `xxx app isn't responding` alert with `close app` and `wait` button about 5 mins later it shows white screen)
I am not using redux. I reviewed console but it doesn't show any error

Thanks

Comment: share the error please

Comment: I think its some kind of rendering loop. I still wonder why the logs aren't showing anything.

Comment: It doesn't call componentWillMount() and componentDidMount(), and even render() functions when restored from background, it's very strange.

Comment: is it possible for you to post your code ?

Comment: yes, which file do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading `mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` version.
Thanks